# Is there a documentation for jquery.couch.js?

Tags: documentation, couchdb, couchapp

Is there a documentation for jquery.couch.js, the standard JavaScript API that ships with CouchDB?

In many blog posts and tutorial this API is used and to some degree explained how to use it. But is there some always up-to-date documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Google is your friend.](http://arandomurl.com/2011/04/02/jquery-couch-js-documentation.html)

http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/index.html

Comment: nice! Last time I did some extended googling it wasn't there yet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It always makes me nuts when responders answer by saying to Google. That's exactly how I got here. As did the vast majority of people who view your response. </venting> Oh well, at least you answered the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another documentation for jquery.couch.js plugin

http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a lot of methods : 
http://daleharvey.github.io/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.html